# Google sharing without login not working

Tags: ios, google-plus

My code for sharing is as below:

```
id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];

// This line will fill out the title, description, and thumbnail from
// the URL that you are sharing and includes a link to that URL.

[shareBuilder setTitle:@"Try Sharing g+" description:@"demo" thumbnailURL:nil];

[shareBuilder open];
if (![shareBuilder open]) {
    NSLog(@"Status: error (see console)....");
}
```

But I am getting errors like:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You must specify |clientID| for |GPPSignIn|'

From google developer link https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/basic-share its saying that I can share without login into google+, still its not working.
Please suggest some solution.

Comment: you cannot share a data without login

Comment: @karthikeyan but why this google developer link https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/basic-share saying so?

Comment: yes correct but it will redirect to default browser and ask you to do login..

Comment: @karthikeyan yes I want the same functionality but its not even redirect to default browser. My app is crashing with message :
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You must specify |clientID| for |GPPSignIn|'

Comment: Before that you need to follow https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started and https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

Comment: @karthikeyan I have followed the link https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started to create app but now I want to make code like  https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/basic-share

Comment: do you have client id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67837/discussion-between-karthikeyan-and-pooja).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of whether or not you want the user to be logged in, you must, at least, specify your clientID ahead of time:

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance]; 
signIn.clientID = kYourClientIDHere; 

id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];
[shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/restaurant/sf/1234567/"]];
[shareBuilder open];
```

The sample code / documentation you referenced does not make this clear - yet it is a requirement nonetheless.

After fixing your code, if you examine the URL that is opened in the browser you will see that it includes your ClientID.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLComponents* urlComponents = [[NSURLComponents alloc]
                                      initWithString:@"https://plus.google.com/share"];

```
urlComponents.queryItems = @[[[NSURLQueryItem alloc]
                              initWithName:@"url"
                              value:@"www.brahmasys.com"]];

NSURL* url = [urlComponents URL];         // Open the URL in the device's browser
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: Is this accepted in apple? Im currently using GIDSignIn and i cant find anything to be able to share things to googleplus..